# Asynchronous raycasting and pathfinding

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've just downloaded the new Unity (beta) 2018.1b version and I'm wondering how to use all the new fanciness they introduced, like the two things mentioned in the topic. Can I just put pathfinding and raycasting code into `IJob.Execute` method definition and it will just work, or are there some more specialized structs I need to extend in order for those two to work (like `IJobParallelForTransform`)?

I'm asking this because the docs and google search uncovered nothing, which is to be expected, since this new version was released earlier today, but maybe someone already has some knowledge.

Comment: Didn't know 2018 version is already released.  I would like to test this but don't have time to install new version and play with it. It's better that you ask this question on the new [2018.1 version forum](https://forum.unity.com/forums/2018-1-beta.143/).You will likely get a reply from one their engineers. Once you get your answer, you can come back and post it here.

Comment: Huh, I've actually never used their forum. I'll do what you suggest, thanks!

Comment: Their question and answer site sucks! The forum side is fine. You will likely get a reply especially on the forum for experimental or beta updates. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested in this topic, here's the discussion on unity forums: https://forum.unity.com/threads/asynchronous-raycasting-and-pathfinding.511973/#post-3349101

Comment: I saw the great reply from their engineers. Right now, pathfinding and raycasts are not currently supported with `iJob`. but should be in 8.1.4 beta release.